# Why can't I get a Facebook user's name?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the following code, which logs in and out of Facebook fine, but I cannot get the user's name to appear - at the moment I can't even figure out if I'm failing to grab it or simply failing to display it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>New Document</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"><div id="fb-root"></div><script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId    : 'my_api_key',
    status   : true,
    cookie   : true,
    xfbml    : true,
    oauth    : true,
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
    window.location = "http://my.site/doc";
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function() {
    window.location = "http://my.site/";
  });
  FB.api('/me', function(user) {
    if (user) {
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        name.innerHTML = user.name;
    }
  });
};
(function(d) {
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));

</script></head>
```

Comment: What if you `alert(user.name);` instead? `name` variable contains a dom element you searched for 2 lines above.

Comment: Didn't even mean to leave that alert in, was just testing. Changing it to user.name has no affect.

Comment: Do you have `<span id="name"></span>` in your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you come into the

`FB.api('/me', function(user) {    if (user) {`

I don't see if you're checking for either an error code or for if the user is not even logged in.

You should surround your FB.api call inside of a FB.getLoginStatus() call to ensure you're logged in.

Comment: I know I should be doing this, and will add it, but even if I'm definitely logged in it still doesn't get me the name.

Comment: Check out the code I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/R4g47/3/  This should work for you.  Click [run] to run the demo. Accept the app.  Then click [run] again to see the results of the /me call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    name.innerHTML = user.name;
    alert(name)
```

says that you need to have

```
    <img id='image' />
    <div id='name'></div>
```

in your markup (between body tag)

Comment: Hmm, didn't think that would make any difference until I wanted the image, but I'm now getting "undefined" as the name and a missing image. Bit closer thanks!

Comment: Hi @tsvallender,

You are supposed to put all your fb related js code after `<body>`.

How can you put `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in your head section ?